# Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics timeout in large mailbox

Tags: powershell, timeout, exchange-server

When running Exchange Powershell "Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics" command on large mailbox (10's of thousands of folders) a timeout occurs and I have found no way of getting the results i need.  My next step is to create a full command line application or UWP to achieve the administrative results needed.

Does anyone know of a way to retreive list of empty folders in this situation?

This works in normal mailboxes but returns timeout error in large mailbox:

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $mailboxidentity | 
    Where {$_.identity -like "*Inbox*" -and $_.ItemsInFolder -eq 0} | 
    Select Identity | 
    Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\emptyfolders.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you use `-FolderScope` to narrow your focus does it change the behavior?

Comment: Your title says `Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics` but your code says `Get-MailboxFolderStatistics`, which one do you use?

Comment: both forms of the command timeout (get-mailboxfolderstatistics and get-exomailboxfolderstatistics)...

Comment: i will check out folderscope and see if that helps... fyi:  this mailbox has 41,000 folders plus...

Comment: I ended up writing something in c# using microsoft graph and just pulling the data in 500 result pages... was able to move forward.

Comment: folderscope did allow PS to return results!  funny, that this works even though 99.99999% of the folders are in the inbox scope

Comment: One thing i  have found is that not all "displayName" properties from the graph seem to match the actual display name shown in outlook.

Comment: @EdAlexander what graph calls did you use? I need to do the same thing.